# Set the file size limit using the FFMPEG API

Tags: c++, encoding, ffmpeg

My task, when encoding raw audio data, is to limit the recording when the set maximum file size is reached. To determine the current duration of an audio file, I use data from packet:

```cpp
// Calculating the current value of the time duration of the media file.
packet.duration = av_rescale_q(packet.duration, p_iStream->time_base, p_oStream->time_base);
m_duration     += packet.duration;
```

But when calculating the file size in this way, it does not work:

```cpp
// Calculating the current value of the media file size.  
m_fileSize += packet.buf->size;
```

How do I determine the file size in real time? I can't use other classes to work with the file. This file is already opened by ffmpeg, and it cannot be opened from the outside.

Comment: avio_size() on the pb you're using.

Comment: @Gyan thank you very much. I forgot about the `avio` header :)